# Zero set of continuous and monotone function is convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose that $F:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is continuous and monotone, i.e.,
\begin{align}
(\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}) \quad \langle F(x) - F(y), x-y \rangle \geq 0.
\end{align}
Show that
\begin{align}
 \text{zer }F := \{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\mid F(x) = 0\}
\end{align}
is convex.

Let $x,y\in \text{zer }F$ and $\theta\in(0,1)$. Let $z=\theta x + (1-\theta) y$ and $\alpha>0$. Then
\begin{align}
\langle F(z) - F(x \mp \alpha(1-\theta) F(z)), y-x \pm \alpha F(z) \rangle &\geq 0, \\
\langle F(z) - F(y \mp \alpha \theta F(z)), x-y \pm \alpha F(z) \rangle &\geq 0.
\end{align}
This feels close.

What about a proof that does not use the Minty trick as below?

Comment: I think using a contradiction argument will be quite straightforward, as in assume there exists $x,y\in zer F$, $\lambda\in(0,1)$ such that the convex combination is not in the zero set.  You should be able to consider $F$ on the line segment and get a contradiction by monotonicity and continuity.

Comment: @FinnPillar to me it feels like a proof by contradiction and a direct proof would use the same ideas.

Comment: An obstacle for any proof is that one cannot reduce the problem to the one-dimensional situation by considering a line segment. Then one gets at best $\langle F(z),z\rangle=0$, which is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is proof based on the so-called Minty trick for maximal monotone operators. It based on  the equivalence
$$
F(x) =0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \langle F(y), y-x \rangle \ge0 \quad \forall y.
$$
The direction $\Rightarrow$ follows from monotonicity. Now assume the right condition. Take $w$ and set $y:=x+tw$. Then
$$
\langle F(x+tw), tw \rangle \ge0 .
$$
Dividing by $t$ and passing to the limit $t\searrow0$ proves
$$
\langle F(x),w\rangle =0 \quad \forall w.
$$
This uses continuity.
Hence $F(x)=0$. And the equivalence is proven.

Then
$$
zer(F) = \{x :\ F(x) =0 \} = \bigcap_{y} \{x :\ \langle F(y), y-x\rangle \ge0 \}
$$
is an intersection of convex sets, hence convex.

Comment: Same idea as in Bauschke and Combettes: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-48311-5